# Understanding docker

Tags: docker

I want to make sure that I understand docker correctly here. My principal goal is to distribute little pieces of software (usually with full source-code) I write in Python/Haskell or C++ to my friends and colleagues.

I myself work on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. But often the people whom I distribute it to work on different machines and operating systems and they don't have the libraries needed to run my codes.

If I understand docker correctly, is the following a valid use case?

- Set up an empty docker folder
- Write code and install all the libraries and dependencies in that folder.
- Upload it to the docker cloud
- Tell my friend to download it on his Windows machine or Mac and run the code without any fuss.

Is this a good summary of what docker allows? If so that is fantastic news, since it will help me a lot in making my research work reproducible 
and distributable across multiple machines.

I don't really understand the explanations online when they compare this software against virtual machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comprehension of docker is close, but not quite the meaning of docker ;)

Docker is a *container* service designed for placing your application on a system in a way such that the only thing a user needs to do is download the container and run it. Docker containers aim to make applications universal and versatile on ALL environments and a great way to package your needed dependencies all to one place so its not a hassle. With a docker container, a user can develop an application, package it, and distribute to any platform that can run the docker daemon itself.

It is fair that you view docker as a virtual machine. It can house multiple operating systems, partition off data as needed, so why wouldnt it be a VM? The answer is because of where docker operates which is inside the hypervisor. All a container provides is the necessary components needed to run your application and nothing more.

If you wanted to share your application, doing it through the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) is the aim that you want to follow. Users that have installed and are running the docker daemon can simply do a `docker pull IMAGE_NAME` and a `docker run IMAGE_NAME` to start their newly installed container. [The installation of docker varies from machine to machine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) so its up to the end user to get it set up correctly.

There is the base of docker; universal use and versioning support for applications of all nature. If you havent read it already, try checking out the [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/) for more information!

Comment: Thank you so much for a great explanation. So all the people whom I share my source code with, will just need to take the pain of installing the docker appropriate for their OS right? Also what if I develop an executable on my Ubuntu machine with all the necessary shared library dependencies in the container? Will that executable run on a Windows machine assuming it has docker installed?

Comment: @smilingbuddha : based on what docker claims to do and what i have seen, yes. Docker will run that executable from within its contained environment. If you are developing your own containers, it will contain all the packages and dependencies that you tell it to contain. You just need to make sure of a few things. Just remember; you always need the path to your executable application. Beyond that you can [build and operate your container how you see fit, even from within a container!](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/)